# How exactly is [att~=val] different from [att*=val] in CSS Attribute Selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Maybe I am missing something, but they seem similar. If you use for example...

```
a[alt~="thumb"]
```

or...

```
a[alt*="thumb"]
```

What can I narrow my selection down to differently? I am at the understanding that ~ gives you a partial match in the quotes while the * gives you a partial match. I am going to fiddle with the code a little, but since I could not find a question on the subject here, thought it would make a good topic either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the JQuery help (which supports the standard selectors):

```
a[alt~="thumb"]
```

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a
>   value containing a given word, delimited by spaces. This selector
>   matches the test string against each word in the attribute value,
>   where a "word" is defined as a string delimited by whitespace. The
>   selector matches if the test string is exactly equal to any of the
>   words.

```
a[alt*="thumb"]
```

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a
>   value containing the a given substring. This is the most generous of
>   the jQuery attribute selectors that match against a value. It will
>   select an element if the selector's string appears anywhere within the
>   element's attribute value. Compare this selector with the Attribute
>   Contains Word selector (e.g. [attr~="word"]), which is more
>   appropriate in many cases.

Basically the selector `~=` only matches if the value is found surrounded by white space. The selector `*=` matches if the value is found anywhere.

```
<div alt='heading navigation'>
<div alt='head'>
```

`div[alt~='head']` would match only the second div, but `div[alt*='head']` would match both.

Comment: Ahh, I noticed at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ they use the term "Borrowing from CSS 1–3".

Comment: Here's the spec link for anyone who prefers referring to the CSS spec over the jQuery documentation for standard CSS selectors, like myself: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 1):

`[att~=value]` is a **contains word** selector.

So a `[alt="foo"]` selector will match `<a alt="foo bar">` but will not match `<a alt="foobar">`.

`[alt*="foo"]` will match both though, because this doesn't discriminate on words or whatever. As long as it's in the value, it hits.