# What is the different between [att|=val] and [att~=val] in css

Tags: html, css

I am facing very difficulty to understand these two different attribute in CSS `[att|=val] and [att~=val]`. Can anyone simply give me explanation for it

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442963/how-exactly-is-att-val-different-from-att-val-in-css-attribute-selectors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530852/what-is-the-difference-between-pipe-and-caret-attribute-selectors

Comment: `[attr|=val]` in this condition are really available?

Comment: yes @prasad, that's why i am so much confused on it

Comment: @P.S.F.Romesh With my knowledge `[attr|=val]` not there.Where did you find this type?

Comment: hi @prasad this is the link i got https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/ thanks for reply

Comment: Gah @Michael Coker I thought those were the same, but it only partially answers it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp @P.S.F.Romesh see the all css selector reference with example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[attr|=val]` matches a word in `val` in any form, so `[class=div]` would match `.my-div`, `.div`, but not `.mydiv`.

`[attr~=val]` matches a complete word in `val`, so `[class~=div]` would match `.div`, but not `.mydiv` or `.my-div`.

**Example:**

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="myDiv2"></div>
<div id="new-div"></div>
```

CSS

```
div[id|=myDiv] {
  /* Matches the first div */
}
div[id|=my]{
  matches first two divs
}
div[id|=new]{
  /* Matches second div - the hyphen counts as a word separator */
}
div[id~=Div]{
  /* Matches nothing - "Div" is not a separate word */
}
```

Comment: 1) It's [attr|=val] with a pipe, not [attr=val] 2) "contains" is a little vague, it helps to be very specific here since other attribute selectors exist that match values containing substrings.

Comment: This answer is not correct according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). You are confusing `[attr~=val]` with `[attr*=val]`, I think?