# Selecting ID based on substring

Tags: javascript

I have a group of images in my `HTML` with the ID's `"Hole#" ex: "Hole1", "Hole2" ... "HoleN".` These IMG tags are loading a locally stored image. My goal is to print an `alert` when one of the images is clicked.

I found [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128516/what-is-the-different-between-att-val-and-att-val-in-css#42128908) StackOverflow question that I thought would answer my question. I've incorporated it into my code below. Unfortunately it did not achieve the desired effect.

```
//Dynamically creates images
for (let i = 1; i <= NUM_HOLES; i++) {
    let HoleID = `"hole${i}"`;
    let HoleIDPic = `"holePic${i}"`;
    holesString +=
    `<div id=`+ HoleID + `>
    <img id=` + HoleIDPic + ` src="" />
    </div>`
}

window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("img[id|=hole]").onclick = function()
      {
         alert("Clicked");
      };
   };
```

HTML:

```
   <section id="holes">

   </section>
```

replacing the code `"img[id|=hole]"` with `"hole1"` does work however (for hole1), So I've concluded its my syntax the `ID` selection.

Comment: Try this: `img[id*='Hole']`.

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('img[id^=hole]')` will get you images whose id's begin with 'hole'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <section id="holes"></section>

    <script>    
      loadImages(2);
      
      function loadImages(NUM_HOLES){
        
        const sectionHoles = document.getElementById('holes');

        //Dynamically creates images
        for (let i = 1; i <= NUM_HOLES; i++) {

            let HoleID = `hole${i}`;
            let HoleIDPic = `holePic${i}`;

            let div = document.createElement('div');
            let img = document.createElement('img');

            div.id = HoleID;
            img.id = HoleIDPic;
            img.src = "someimage.png";

            // put image element in div
            div.appendChild(img);
            // put div in section
            sectionHoles.appendChild(div);

            // adding event listener to the img element
            document.getElementById(HoleIDPic).addEventListener('click', function(){
                alert(HoleIDPic + 'clicked');
            });
        }
   }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This solved my issue, I'd would up vote you if I could - please accept my gratitude instead! Cheers!

Comment: Could you add some information about *how* this solves the problem? I'm glad that Chris thinks this solves his issue, but other readers won't be able to read it easily without text.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of using similar `id`s on all images is the wrong approach.

Use a common CSS class instead. Then, to find out which image was clicked, use a single delegate listener and make use of the event object that is automatically passed to your click handler. I'm showing you an example with buttons instead of images:

```js
const buttonDiv = document.querySelector('.buttons');

// lets add some buttons
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.type = 'button';
  button.className = 'button';
  button.textContent = 'Button Number ' + i;
  buttonDiv.appendChild(button);
}

// now let's add a delegate click listener on the div containing the buttons
buttonDiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // in any event listener, the event object has a `target` property, telling you which element the event was raised on
  // this allows us to only react in the click listener if the clicked element meets certain conditions
  if (event.target.matches('button.button')) 
    console.log('you clicked on ' + event.target.textContent);
})
```

```css
.buttons {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great to solve this problem, very elegant. I my problem was also solved by another person above, but I appreciate the help! In the future I'll be sure to use this method alternatively as It looks cleaner than my current method.